# Manipulate this summation with Exp

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, exponential-sum

I am trying to manipulate this summation such that I have a summation dependent only on $i,j,k$ and any other outside influence or dependence on $B$ is left outside of this sum:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{-B\sqrt{i^2+j^2+k^2}}$$

This could be rewritten:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(e^{-B}\right)^{\sqrt{i^2+j^2+k^2}}$$  Or 
 $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(e^{\sqrt{i^2+j^2+k^2}}\right)^{-B}$$
Or multiple other ways, but you get the idea.

The reason I want to do this is because I could potentially handle the summation on $(i,j,k)$ independently, which would be great!

I've looked at trying things like manipulating with $Ln$ functions but that always seems to diverge...

Also, it is not possible to use this replacement:
$$r\equiv\sqrt{i^2+j^2+k^2}$$
and then
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}e^{-B\cdot{r}}$$
Because $r$ is not guaranteed to be an integer (it usually isn't).

Any tricks/thoughts are much appreciated!
(Also, $B$ is positive and real)

Comment: What is your ultimate purpose of considering this sum? For instance, if you are only interested with the asymptotic behavior with respect to $B$, then much softer approach can be made. On the other hand, the sum is of number-theoretic nature and indeed is written as a combination of Jacobi theta functions.

Comment: It's part of a sum over lattice sites in a crystal lattice (for potential energy or force calculations).  The asymptotic behavior is not exactly what I want since terms with N >> 1 go to zero.  However, for programming purposes, it is useful to go to an N value such that the term at that N does not add to the existing variable (you've exceeded the precision of the type you're using).